# SFSafariViewController status bar style

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios9

My app's statusbar style is `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and it's set in my rootViewController as `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

Now I have a problem that when opening `SFSafariViewController` from within my app, it has inherited statusbar style that is light and invisible on the white background of `SFSafariViewController`.

Is there a way to set statusbar style for SFSafariViewController?

P.S. I tried to subclass SFSafariViewController and override this method but it doesn't help.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Update:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:] does the trick, but this method is deprecated in iOS 9.

Comment: It seems that the problem appeared because I haven't set uiviewcontroller-based status bar appearance key to YES in the info.plist. I rewrite status-bar styling code to use view-controller based way and everything works perfect

Comment: @ClayEllis sorry, missed it at the time. Thanks for an answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't have to subclass `SFSafariViewController` at all.

**Just set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` on your instance of `SFSafariViewController` and it will handle the rest on its own.**

This works because its own default `preferredStatusBarStyle` is, you guessed it, `.default`. The view hierarchy is still relying on the presenting view controller for status bar appearance, so by setting `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` to `true`, it will be the receiver asked for status bar appearance.

*TL;DR*

```
safariViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

(This behavior is overridden, doesn't work, when `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` is set to `NO` in your Info.plist)

Comment: Thanks for the most elegant solution

Comment: @Alex Any clarification on why it hasn't? I just worke for me and it should based on Clay's information that the SafariVC is the one setting the colour of the status bar text.

Comment: Just a heads up, this doesn't work if you have the property key "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" in your info list set to NO

Answer (score 9):

It is not the best solution, but it works.

```
class MySafariViewContoller: SFSafariViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(false)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
    }
}
```

Change .Default and .LightContent as you prefer.

Comment: Nice solution, is a way to keep the lower iOS version of the app to 8.0 and still (if the use is on 9.0) use a class that heritage from `SFSafariViewController ` ?

Comment: I've got my answer
`@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class MySafariViewContoller: SFSafariViewController `

Comment: This solution works when `UIModalPresentationStyle` property is set to `fullScreen` else go with @clay-ellis accepted answer above.

Answer (score 8):

You can use extensions.

```
extension SFSafariViewController {

    override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
    }

    override open func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I do this in ObjectiveC?

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
class MyCustomSafariViewController: SFSafariViewController {

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }
}
```

Or private API - if you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want dark status bar style. Updated the answer, tried to subclass but it doesn't work. Can't use private API

Comment: returning `.Default` does not work and actually `preferredStatusBarStyle ` is never called

Comment: Never suggest using private APIs.